# How to export a variable in one make target rule to use in another make target

Tags: gnu-make

I have the following sample code to illustrate what I am trying to do:

```
rulea:
    $(info $$var1 [rulea] is [${var1}])
    $(eval export var1 = true)
    $(info $$var1 [rulea] is [${var1}])

ruleb: rulea
    $(info $$var1 ruleb is [$(var1)])
    ifeq ($(value var1),true)
    $(info TEST9 $$var1 [ruleb] is [${var1}])
endif
```

`var1` can be printed in `ruleb` but cannot be used in the `ifeq` statement. I think they are running in different shells therefore it cannot be seen. Is there a way to achieve this though?

Comment: `ifeq` is pre-processing. Use `$(if ...)` and the like for runtime evaluation.

Comment: could you please elaborate a bit on how to use `$(if ...)` in this case? I have tried the following command but it still not work:
`$(if $(filter "true",$(var1)),@echo "var1 is true")`

Comment: You're almost there. It's `$(filter true,$(var1))`, without the quotes. Or just `$(if $(var1),@echo "var1 is true")` since it's empty otherwise.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I tried both your suggestions, but got the following error message: `Makefile_vartest:40: *** missing separator.  Stop.` any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Think files.
*Make* likes files.
Keeps your makefiles parallel safe (kind of the whole point of using *make*).

```
rulea:
    Some other stuff...
    echo ${var1} >$@

ruleb: rulea
# Here the file ruleb (or more conveniently, $<) has what you want
    command-that-needs-var1 -i $< -o $@
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I figured passing files maybe more reliable than passing variables. My concern is that between the executions of rulea and ruleb, if user accidentally deletes that file, ruleb will not see var1.

Comment: You mean your user fiddles with build files during a build? Nice.